# No producer. type configuration property in latest apache kafka documentation

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

Is the producer.type configuration supported in the current versions of Kafka? I do not see the producer.type configuration property in the documentation. However, there are configuration properties related to batching. Why is it so? Are all producers now async? Or have they removed async behaviour for producers?

Answer (score 0):

Producers are async in that they return a future and you can wait on the future to complete in your code before sending the next message to achieve synchronous behaviour, assuming acks are set greater than zero, of course.